# Convert a xaml file to an bitmap

Tags: xaml, bitmap

is it possible to convert a xaml-file to an image file of some sort?
I have some xaml-files describing a GUI, and a want to get a 'preview' of them at runtime.

Greets,

Jürgen

Comment: Look into printing. Is this WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: You can consider installing expression builder.

Comment: Its in WPF. How would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) can help you ?

the idea is to render a visual element into a bitmap...

[this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/07/03/rendertargetbitmap-tips.aspx) describes the use

Comment: interesting suggestion. Does it require an interactive session?

Comment: @gigantt.com: i'm not sure, i didn't try in an asp.net app